# Rails relation select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :courses, :through => :participants
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tests, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :participants
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    belongs_to :user
  end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
    has_many :results, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The Idea is that a user **has_and_belongs_to_many** courses, the course **has_many** tests, and every test **has_and_belongs_to_many** users (results).
So what is the best query to select every Result from a single **Course** (not test), and also the query to select every Result from a single Course, but from one user.

Thanks!

Comment: By giving votes to answers that you think are good. By selecting the green checkmark (aka 'that answered my question') to the answer that you believe is the best and that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results from a specific course - given that the only bridge between the two is the test model you will need to include the test in the query.

```
Result.find(:all, :conditions => ["tests.course_id = ?",@course.id], :include => :test)
```

For the second query:

```
Result.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND tests.course_id = ?",@user.id, @course.id], :include => :test)
```